# Cannot add new member numbers

Tags: javascript

I am the webmaster for a small organisation and am trying to add new member numbers in a JavaScript file to allow new members to access the members only section - but all the 10 new numbers I have added simply don't register.  All help suggestions and advice welcome

I have taken over this website from earlier webmaster who was dyslexic ....

The script is........

```
function myFunction(mynumber) {

    var fruits = [
        "001", "122", "128", "130", "149", "159", "168", "170", "172", "179", "181", "188", "198",
        "206", "213", "216", "223", "230", "238", "239", "240", "246", "249", "251", "257", "264", "266", "268", "272", "273", "282", "287", "293",
        "311", "320", "324", "340", "352", "356", "358", "368", "374", "379", "383", "384", "385", "390", "391", "393", "394", "399",
        "416", "419", "423", "426", "430", "437", "445z", "446", "448", "449", "450", "451", "452", "456", "461", "463", "472", "476", "478", "483", "485", "486", "497", "498",
        "502", "505z", "775", "508", "512", "515", "524", "525x", "528", "530", "533", "534", "536", "541", "547", "548",
        "550z", "553", "556", "558z", "559", "561", "564", "566", "569", "571", "579", "580", "582", "585", "589x", "591", "593", "595", "597", "598",
        "600", "601x", "605", "606", "607z", "608", "609", "610", "612", "615", "616", "618", "619", "623x", "625", "626", "632",
        "633z", "637", "638", "639", "641z", "642", "643", "644", "645", "646", "647z", "649",
        "651", "652", "653", "654", "655", "657", "661", "662", "665x", "666", "667", "668", "670", "672", "674",
        "676", "677", "678", "679", "680", "681", "683", "684", "685x", "686", "687", "688", "689", "690",
        "691z", "692","693", "694", "695", "696", "697", "698", "699z", "700",
        "701", "702", "703", "704", "705", "706", "707", "708", "709", "710",
        "711", "712", "713", "714", "715", "716", "717", "718", "719", "720",
        "721", "722", "723", "724", "725", "726", "727", "728", "729", "730",
        "731", "732", "733", "734", "735", "736", "737", "738", "739", "740",
        "741", "742", "743", "744", "745", "746", "747", "748", "749", "750",
        "751", "752", "753", "754", "755", "756", "757", "758", "759", "760",
        "761", "762", "763", "764", "765", "766", "767", "768", "769", "149", "770",
        "771", "772", "773", "774", "775", "776", "777", "778", "779", "780",
        "781", "782", "783", "784", "785", "786", "787", "788", "789", "790",


    ];
    var a = fruits.indexOf(mynumber);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;

    var gotopage = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.org.uk/ESCmembers/"
    var ispage = (unescape('%6D%65%6D%62%65%72%73'));

    gotopage=gotopage + ispage +  ".html"

    if (a == -1) {
        greeting = "Input not valid";
    } else {
        greeting = "Input OK";
        window.location.assign(gotopage)
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
}

//unescape('%6D%65%6D%62%65%72%73')); = members
```

Comment: i dont see where and how u tried to add a number? should be as easy as `fruits.push("123")` . Also it should be clear that everybody can access the "member-only" area by just entering the members url

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `myFunction("790");` with ""
and not `myFunction(790);`

The elements in the array are strings and not integers